# HTML Audio Element in iOS Safari displays weirdly

Tags: html, ios, audio, safari

I have HTML `<audio>` elements in a page. The page and the audio elements look and work fine on a computer in all browsers. When the page first loads in Safari on iOS, the audio elements/players look ok. But, when I pinch the page to be smaller, the audio players shrink down to just a play button and they display on top of neighboring elements - the player buttons are actually quite large relative to the neighboring elements (see the screenshot below).

[When I open the page (which is NOT optimized for mobile) in Safari, it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHEl5.jpg).

[When I pinch the page, it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFUbW.jpg)

The code is simple:
Each audio on the page is defined like this:

```
  <audio controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload">
     <source src="http://somesite.com/music/some-song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     Your browser does not support the 'audio' element
  </audio>
```

and there's some CSS that I have played around with to try to make it work and it currently is:

```
audio {
    height: 25px;
    min-height: 10px;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
    display: block;
}
```

What's going on? Is there a fix?

Comment: Same problem. Trying to solve it lead me here...